# Sql запрос с аналитикой

Tags: sql, oracle

Пишу запрос, где решил перенести аналитику из where в join но вылетает ошибка:

> ORA-00934: групповая функция здесь не разрешена

Вот мой запрос.

```
select count(*) 
  from WC_MAIN m
  left join WC_1_2_LIST l 
    on m.SHOP_ID = l.SHOP_ID 
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = l.PIPE_YEAR 
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = l.PIPE_NUMBER 
   and m.EDIT_STATE = 0 
   and l.EDIT_STATE = 0
  left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p 
    on m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID 
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER 
   and p.EDIT_STATE = 0 
   and min(p.ENTER_DATE) > max(m.ENTER_DATE)
```

Как можно эту аналитику сделать, чтобы пока что не загружать where, а дальше уже подумаю как лучше сделать. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: а вы сделать то что хотите этим запросом?

Comment: MIN/MAX нельзя использовать во WHERE - группировка выполняется ПОСЛЕ отбора.

Comment: Почитайте про групповые функции и порядок выполнения запроса. Сначала выполняется отбор данных, группировка после. Вы же пытаетесь пихнуть группировку куда-то туда. Придумайте новую логику.

Comment: зачем вам там вообще min и max ?

Comment: @lDrakonl для сравнения записей в двух таблицах, похоже всё таки я перемудрил, придётся указывать это в where. По крайней мере пока что. Ведь вроде бы это не единственный способ. Можно же ещё и вложенностью. Но это я потом подумаю(мысли в слух).

Comment: Вы опять пишите `count(*)`, а после того как вам напишут ответы вдруг окажется, что вам нужен вовсе не count и группировать вы вообще не хотели ? Опишите, что конкретно вы ожидаете получить после выполнения запроса. какую роль в запросе играют эти сравнения min/max. Условия с групповыми функциями можно писать в HAVING, но вот даст ли это действительно то, что вы хотите получить

Comment: @Mike вы правы. В итоге мне нужно не `count(*)`. Это просто для примера что бы выбирать быстрей. Из огромной таблицы. В итоге будет просто несколько полей, порядка 10-15 из связанных таблиц. И нужно что бы выбрались записи где минимальная дата таблицы WC_4_8_PRIEMKA была больше максимальной записи таблицы которую я ещё даже не привязал к этому запросу просто сделал пока что это с другой. А смысл в том что есть пункты назначения по которым проходит элемент. И сначала этот элемент на пункте который я ещё не добавил а потом нужно проследить дошёл ли он до пункта 4_8 в этом смысл сравнения дат.

Comment: Чтобы более опытные коллеги подсказали вам оптимальное решение нужно в вопросе описать всю структуру и подробно описать нужный результат. Без этого вы не получите точный ответ.  Максимум что вам могут подсказать это методы, часть из которых будут неоптимальны или вообще неприменимы к вашей структуре.

Comment: Тогда надо начинать с того, какие именно данные и из каких таблиц должны быть на выходе. Вы же понимаете, что любой join с таблицей где более одной записи по условиям объединения сразу перемножает количество записей на выходе. А когда клеится еще третья таблица, начинается выдача всех возможных перестановок. И дальше либо мы делаем group by, либо если он не приемлем, выносим что то в подзапросы или ищем еще какие то пути. Если можно сгруппировать, так добавьте group by и попробуйте написать условия в HAVING.

Comment: @Deft мне в принципе пока что и нужен пример использования групповых функций что бы впихнуть аналитику в запрос. Так как просто  сложное задание и пока что всё строится на написании запроса. Если конкретнее строю отчёт. И вот пока что сам по пути всё соединяю у себя в голове и в запросе)

Comment: И никогда в примере не пишите count() когда вам нужны будут отдельные записи без группировки, потому что правильные решения задачи для count() могут быть абсолютно не применимы при работе с отдельными записями

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Учту на будущее. Пока что тогда построю запрос до конца как я его понимаю а после уже буду спрашивать если что то будет не получаться или т.п. Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: Ну пример то простой `group by некие поля having min(p.ENTER_DATE) > max(m.ENTER_DATE)` а вот применим ли этот подход в вашем случае не зная точную структуру сказать невозможно

Comment: @Mike хорошо я попробую. Спасибо за пример.

Answer (score 0):

Из комментария автора ясно, что необходимо проследить путь детали.
Это можно сделать через внешнее соединение:

```
with s1 (ID, ED)
  as (select 1
           , to_date('2015-05-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      union all
      select 2
           , to_date('2015-05-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      union all
      select 3
           , to_date('2015-05-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      )
   , s2 (ID, ED)
  as (select 1
           , to_date('2015-07-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      union all
      select 2
           , to_date('2016-05-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      union all
      select 3
           , to_date('2015-05-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      )
   , s3 (ID, ED)
  as (select 1
           , to_date('2015-07-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      union all
      select 2
           , to_date('2016-07-05','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      union all
      select 3
           , to_date('2015-05-15','yyyy-mm-dd')
      from dual
      )

select s1.id as id_1 
     , s1.ED as ed_1
     , s2.id as id_2 
     , case
         when s2.ED > s1.ED
         then s2.ED
         else NULL
       end as ed_2
     , s3.id as id_3 
     , case
         when s3.ED > s2.ED
         then s3.ED
         else NULL
       end as ed_2
  from s1
     , s2
     , s3
where s1.ID = s2.id(+)
  and s2.ID = s3.id(+)
```

Результат: первая деталь во втором пункте, вторая в третьем и третья не двигалась.

```
ID_1    ED_1    ID_2    ED_2    ID_3    ED_2
1   05/15/2015  1   07/15/2015  1       -
2   05/15/2015  2   05/15/2016  2   07/05/2016
3   05/15/2015  3       -       3       -
```

Comment: После выборки можно накрутить и аналитику с групировкой.